# Firefox vs IE : missing ID in element inspector

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I am using IE for testing and use the id of elements to identify them. Now I am trying to support Firefox, but it seems that for a same element, there is no id while there is some in IE. For example, on this site:

https://www.canada.ca/en/services/benefits/publicpensions/cpp/retirement-income-calculator.html

The bottom button 'Report a problem or mistake on this page', if I inspect the element in IE, I get the following:

```
<summary tabindex="0" class="btn btn-default text-center wb-init wb-details-inited" id="wb-auto-12" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Report a problem or mistake on this page</summary>
```

While in Firefox, I get:

```
<summary class="btn btn-default text-center">Report a problem or mistake on this page</summary>
```

Does that mean that for this page, IE is generating the id?

Is there a way I can get it in Firefox?

Comment: No `id` in Chrome either.

Comment: Nor in Opera, seems IE specific

Comment: Seems like you are using some polyfill for `<details>`? seems like that adds some classes and attributes to the element

Comment: I think it's this [wet-boew](https://github.com/wet-boew/wet-boew) which adds that specific id.

Comment: This site was just an example, I have to work with different web sites and was wondering why I cannot see the Id in Firefox

Comment: And yes, I think it`s the function getId in wet-boew that returns the id, but why not in Firefox?